# Don't allow to deactivate Company Portal Intune App as a Device Administrator in Android

Tags: android, microsoft-intune

Is there any way that I could block the user of deactivating the Company Portal app from the Device Administrator in a Android Device. What I'm trying to accomplish is that the user can't uninstall the Intune Company Portal app or unenroll a company owned  device.

Answer (score 1):

You can not prevent a user from uninstalling an app, however you can force the app to be installed every time the device is synchronized with Microsoft Intune.

From https://technet.microsoft.com/library/dn646972.aspx:

> When you deploy an app, depending on the deployment action you choose, the app will be made available for users to install from the company portal, **automatically installed**, or uninstalled.
>
> ...
>
> **Required install** – The app will be automatically installed on devices to which it is deployed.
>
> ...
>
> To define a timeline for the app to be deployed, click the drop-down menu in the Deadline column, and select one of the following options:
>
> **As soon as possible**: During the next synchronization, Microsoft Intune scans devices in the selected groups, and then deploys the app.

Comment: That's a good tip, but what I'm looking for is a way to prevent the user from unenrolling the device, not uninstalling a particular app.

Comment: Then you probably need to edit your question for clarification, because you use this exact phrase, "What I'm trying to accomplish is that the user can't uninstall the app..."

Comment: I think it's preatty clear that "the app" it's "the Company Portal app" because it says so before.